# If $\sum_n \frac{1}{\alpha_n}$ is convergent, what can we say about $\min_{r,s}{}_{+} |\alpha_r-\alpha_s|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha_n$ a sequence of real numbers. If
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{\alpha_n}$$
is convergent, what can we say about $\min_{r,s}{}_{+} |\alpha_r-\alpha_s|$? I thought, for example, you could say $\min_{r,s}{}_{+} |\alpha_r-\alpha_s|\leq 1$ but I could find a counterexample to show that this is false.

**EDIT**
$\min_{+} f$ will denotes the least positive value when $f$ ranges over a finite set of non-negative values. This means, for example, that $\min_{r,s}{}_{+} |\alpha_r-\alpha_s|\neq 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\min_{r,s}$? I can make your objective zero for any sequence, convergent or divergent, by prepending $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 1$.

Comment: @user7530, thanks for your remark. I've edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find convergent series of given kind with $$\min_{r,s} |\alpha_r-\alpha_s|\le K$$ For that consider the series $$\dfrac{1}{1+\alpha}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$ or $$\min_{r,s} |\alpha_r-\alpha_s|\ge K$$ for any given $K\in\mathbb{R}^+,$ for that consider $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$